Where to implement the encryption on access token in clean architecture of android?
I implemented the Symmetric encryption of access token using Android KeyStore, but where I must do encryption process

Repository class where I receive data from Remote.
View Model class after passing data from repo to view model.

Does encryption need to do in background ?


All your IO should be in a Repository, so by that logic, you should have logic to store/encrypt and retrieve/decrypt logic into your repository itself.
